# Device name in Mac Terminal is a random person's iPhone?

Tags: terminal

I was in terminal today and noticed this:

[image]

Jeremys-Iphone: I have no idea who Jeremy is or have a friend named Jeremy.

Do you know what this means, and how this might have happened?

Thanks!

Comment: It is probably a DHCP-supplied hostname. What probably happened is that the DHCP server had a hostname cached for your IP/MAC in some weird way that had the iPhone's hostname in cache and applied it to your Mac when it requested a lease form the DHCP server.

You can check your computer's actual name in:

System Preferences -> Sharing -> Computer Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `$PS` environment variable for setting prompt:

```
echo $PS1
```

It might be

```
"\h:\W \u$ "
```

If so, your computer name is changed and you can edit it. If not, change it to that form by editing `~/.bash_profile`

Also check that you are really on your Mac and not on an iPhone by this command:

```
uname -m
```

It should be `x86_64` and not `iPhone...`

Comment: You're right, the guy who set up the Internet in the office is named Jeremy. I thought I was hacked... awkward.